# Writing a query without using sub-query

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have two tables, A and B.

They are joined by a common field called id. Table B also has a field post_code and a date attached to that post_code, meaning the first time that post_code was entered into the database.

I need to select the latest post code and join it to a row on table A WITHOUT a sub-query.

I've got a solution with a sub-query but it's taking far too long

TIA

Comment: share the query here, it give more clearity

Comment: The only DBMS I can think of offering a solution for this is PostgreSQL with `DISTINCT ON`. All other DBMS need a subquery, either by filtering a `ROW_NUMBER` result or by using a `MAX(date)` subquery or by applying a `CROSS APPLY` or `LATERAL` subquery. What DBMS are you using and what makes you think you must not use a subquery?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. I have upwards of a 1million rows in table A. On the sub-query solution, that means a sub-query for every row. As I said in my question, it was taking too long.

For people with bigger servers, this may not be a problem but I have to play nice with my co-users who sit opposite me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [APPLY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

```
Create Table #A(Id int)

Create Table #B(Id int, AId int, PostCode VARCHAR(10), DateAdded DATE)

Insert into #A
    Values(1),(2)


Insert into #B
    Values(1,1,'NW1', GETDATE()-100),
          (2,1,'S20', GETDATE()-200)

Select *
From #A A
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 B.*
                FROM #B B
                WHERE A.Id = B.AId
                ORDER BY DateAdded DESC) Latest
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. I hadn't coming across cross-apply before.

Comment: @user2573436: Is this something you after? Your question was not that clear

Comment: I'm a little hazy on SQL concepts, so my question might not be in the clearest terms. I applied your solution and it came up with the exact answer I was looking for, cheers.

Comment: @user2573436: If this is correct answer, why not accept it? [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)